# Form in a table in Zend Framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I read many tutorials on how to make a form inside a table in zend framework but unfortunately  none of them worked for me and I've been spending so much time on it so I decided to ask you guys.
This is my code:

```
public $elementDecorators = array(
        'ViewHelper',
        'Errors',
        array(array('data' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'td', 'class' => 'col2')),
        array('Label', array('tag' => 'td','class'=>'taR')),
        array(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'tr','class' => 'rowA')),
);

public function init()
{

    $this->setName('message');

    $message_id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('message_id');
    $message_id->addFilter('Int');

    $message_content = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('message_content');
    $message_content->setLabel('Message')
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->addFilter('StripTags')
    ->addFilter('StringTrim')
    ->addValidator('NotEmpty')
    ->setAttrib('class', 'frmtb');
    $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
    $username->setLabel('Name')
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->addFilter('StripTags')
    ->addFilter('StringTrim')
    ->addValidator('NotEmpty')
    ->setAttrib('class', 'frmtb');

    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
    $submit->setAttrib('id', 'submitbutton')
    ->setAttrib('class', 'frmbtn');


    //$this->addElements(array($message_id, $username,$message_content, $submit));
    $this->addElement($username,'username',array('decorators' => $this->elementDecorators));
    $this->addElement($message_content,'message_content',array('decorators' => $this->elementDecorators));
    $this->addElement($submit,'submit',array('decorators' => $this->elementDecorators));
}
```

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Ok so I was lucky to find my answer right after I posted this question. [This question about Zend form decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5276104/zend-framework-form-decorators) was really helpful.

My code now looks like this:

```
public function init()
{


    $this->setDecorators(array(
            'FormElements',
            array('HtmlTag',array('tag'=>'table')),
            'Form'
    ));

    $this->setName('message');

    $message_id = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('message_id');
    $message_id->addFilter('Int');

    $message_content = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('message_content');
    $message_content->setLabel('Message')
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->addFilter('StripTags')
    ->addFilter('StringTrim')
    ->addValidator('NotEmpty')
    ->setAttrib('class', 'frmtb');

    $message_content->setDecorators(array(
            'ViewHelper',
            'Errors',
            array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'),
                    array('tag'=>'td','class'=>'element')),
            array('Label',array('tag'=>'td')),
            array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr')),

    ));

    $username = new Zend_Form_Element_Text('username');
    $username->setLabel('Name')
    ->setRequired(true)
    ->addFilter('StripTags')
    ->addFilter('StringTrim')
    ->addValidator('NotEmpty')
    ->setAttrib('class', 'frmtb');

    $username->setDecorators(array(
            'ViewHelper',
            'Errors',
            array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'),
                    array('tag'=>'td','class'=>'element')),
            array('Label',array('tag'=>'td')),
            array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr')),

    ));

    $submit = new Zend_Form_Element_Submit('submit');
    $submit->setAttrib('id', 'submitbutton')
    ->setAttrib('class', 'frmbtn');

    $submit->setDecorators(array(
            'ViewHelper',
            'Errors',
            array(array('data'=>'HtmlTag'),
                    array('tag'=>'td','class'=>'element')),
            array('Label',array('tag'=>'td')),
            array(array('row'=>'HtmlTag'),array('tag'=>'tr')),

    ));


    $this->addElements(array($message_id, $username,$message_content, $submit));
}
```